# SQL external table column length issue

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

I have a `.csv` file in data lake with text column of length 16000. I have to create an external table in Azure SQL to read that `.csv` file data. `nvarchar(max)` / `varchar(max)` are not allowed in external table and I can define column length only up to 4000.

Can some please help me resolve this issue?

Comment: what you are saving in that column ?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround a normal Azure Data Factory copy activity will import the CSV without any problem to Azure SQL and you can put the 16,000 column length data into a NVARCHAR(max) as destination on Azure SQL. Quick and simple.